# MeteorHacks:npm not working ( npm modules in Meteor)

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I have installed MeterorHacks Npm and I added two packages in the .json file :

```
 {
  "cheerio":"0.19.0",
  "request":"2.57.0"
}
```

I have put the required node packages in public directory of meteor.

When I use meteor command, the error I get in cmd is :

It just stops at Building npm-container :

```
C:\Users\Abhishek\new>meteor
[[[[[ C:\Users\Abhishek\new ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
npm-container: updating npm dependencies -- cheerio, request...
   Building package npm-container            \
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong here. This process takes alot of time for some packages. If there is an error it will give a bit more clarity after some time. Such problems can come from an internet connection issue, incorrect binaries for the platform you're on.

But as it stands it's installing the npm dependencies for the first time. It only happens once.

Once the installation is complete it will let you know meteor is running on port x (usually 3000)